# In Google Colaboratory, is there a way to indicate preference for or to require a specific gpu model?

Tags: gpu, benchmarking, google-colaboratory

I am attempting to measure run-time scaling and limits of Google Colaboratory for certain tasks, which likely both depend significantly on the gpu model assigned in the backend. Currently in a notebook, Runtime, Change runtime type, Hardware Accelerator brings up the choices  none, gpu, tpu. There is no ability there to indicate a preference or requirement for a specific gpu model. Is there some way somewhere else, to indicate a preference or requirement for a specific gpu model, or indifference to which gpu model is allocated to the VM for the session? It would be great to have such a capability available. Currently, I just keep trying with new sessions until I get the gpu model I'm looking for, to perform work on a task. This is tedious, and inefficient for both the Google infrastructure and the user.

Comment: Retry has stopped working. First the required model gpu vanished from the population. Later, maybe after too many session terminates and restarts over a period of hours, the account no longer received any gpu availability for about a day.

Comment: I've switched the paradigm from trying to finish benchmarking on one gpu model, to opportunistically starting or continuing benchmarking separately for whichever gpu model I happen to get. Still would like to see an answer, and maybe some new features related to require or prefer a specific gpu model, so I've submitted the idea as feedback (per the Colab FAQ, from an open notebook, Help menu, send feedback)